# Why can't I run imported projects on Android Studio (2017)?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why can't I run imported projects on Android Studio?

My error:

[image]

Comment: migrate to Gradle as the warning at the bottom of AS tells you to and add the proper dependencies

Comment: i did : Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.) from the welcome screen  (see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU0fE.png)  But it didn't work please help

Comment: seems like play-services library isn't added in build.gradle... Could you please add it and sync gradle.

Comment: hi the project i just download it from here : https://codecanyon.net/item/catch-orange-with-admob-and-leaderboard/14190507

Comment: Just try doing it again. Click **File > Close Existing Project** And then 
 **Import Project (Eclipse ADT)**.

Answer (score 1):

As per attachment you shared in question, it seems your project didn't get

**@integer/google_play_services_version**

When you link **Google-play-services** library to your project,

1. You need to add **google_play_services.json** file into your project.

> Project Structure --> App --> Dependencies --> click + for add option for Library --> play-services (x.x.x)

Hope it helped :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18018525)

Comment: @Sagar  I have updated answer with essential part. thanks.